# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError

Tags: tensorflow

I am using tensorflow-gpu 2.3.0 with CUDA_VERSION=8.0.61 and CUDNN_VERSION=6.0.21.
I just run a tensorflow code and get FailedPreconditionError:
'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Failed to allocate scratch buffer for device 0 [Op:VarHandleOp] name: Variable/'
What can I do to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Can you try as per [tested build configuration for TF2.3](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) and let us know?Thanks!